# How to have different footer background color same as per background-color on different pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am creating a webapp in angularjs. I have few pages in this and same footer on each page. The problem is some page have content with white background and some with blue. I want to know how to change background color of footer for each page accordingly.

Here is my `index.html`:

```
<body layout="row" ng-init="populateData();" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="ng-cloak">
<div flex layout="column" role="main">
    <!-- Navigation Bar At Top  -->
    <nav-bar>
    </nav-bar>
    <!-- Navigation Bar Ends -->

    <!--     All Views -->
    <div ui-view layout="row" id="uiView" flex>
    </div>
    <!-- All views ends -->

    <footer  style="background-color: transparent">
        <small>© 2007-2015 xyz.com.</small>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is one of page, which have `background-color` as blue:

```
<div layout="column" class="someclass" style="background-color: blue">
   <!--More HTML here-->
</div>
```

Similarly there are some pages with background color while, Now how should I set background color of footer so that it has color respective to content being displayed onpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `MainCtrl` you can have this variable

```
$rootScope.backColor = "#fff";
```

and change it in other controllers

```
$rootScope.backColor = "#00f";
```

and in the footer html

```
<footer  ng-style="{'background-color':backColor}">
    <small>© 2007-2015 xyz.com.</small>
</footer>
```